# Understanding the publication and implementation of test fixtures

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, java-test-fixtures

For context, what I am trying to achieve being able to use test fixtures cross projects.

Within projects in the same repo, this is no issue and works as expected. However, as an external dependency I struggle to make it work.

First of all, when I am publishing the artifacts I get the following warning/error:

```
Maven publication 'baz' pom metadata warnings (silence with 'suppressPomMetadataWarningsFor(variant)'):
  - Variant testFixturesApiElements:
      - Declares capability foo.bar:baz-test-fixtures:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT which cannot be mapped to Maven
  - Variant testFixturesRuntimeElements:
      - Declares capability foo.bar:baz-test-fixtures:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT which cannot be mapped to Maven
These issues indicate information that is lost in the published 'pom' metadata file, which may be an issue if the published library is consumed by an old Gradle version or Apache Maven.
The 'module' metadata file, which is used by Gradle 6+ is not affected.
```

Dispite this, the artifact is published but the classifier (test-fixtures) is applied *after* the version `foo.bar:baz-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-test-fixtures.jar`. Is this actually intended? I would expect the version to be the last part. **Please correct me if I am wrong here**. According to https://developer.android.com/studio/publish-library/configure-test-fixtures it does seem to me as if it should produce what I expect assuming `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` is defined, which they are (see [Publishing test fixtures with submodules, gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75361829/publishing-test-fixtures-with-submodules-gradle) for my setup).

Assuming what I described above is actually correct, I am unable to actually introduce the jar as a dependency automatically. I have tried to add the jar to the classpath manually which works fine as expected. This is what I have tried:

`testImplementation(testFixtures("foo.bar:baz:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT"))`
`testImplementation(testFixtures("foo.bar:baz:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-test-fixtures"))`

I have tried renaming the jar file itself, but this does not work either.

Going back to the issue during publication. Is there something I have missed to ensure this capability of my artifact perhaps?

EDIT:

```
// Build.gradle.kts in baz submodule
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("java-test-fixtures")
}

dependencies {
    testFixturesApi(project(":baz"))
}
```

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar

// values, ie val javaVersion: String by project.

allprojects {
    group = "${projectGroup}.${rootProject.name}"
    version = projectVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.1" apply false
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.0"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.0"
    id("maven-publish")
}

tasks {
    withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
        targetCompatibility = javaVersion
    }

    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = javaVersion
        }
    }

    withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    withType<Wrapper> {
        gradleVersion = "7.3"
    }

    withType<BootJar> {
        enabled = false
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    apply {
        plugin("io.spring.dependency-management")
        plugin("org.springframework.boot")
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa")
        plugin("maven-publish")
    }

    tasks {
        register("prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel") {}

        withType<BootJar> {
            enabled = false
        }

        withType<Test> {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }

        getByName<Jar>("jar") {
            enabled = true
        }

    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>(project.name) {
                artifactId = "${shortName}-${tasks.jar.get().archiveBaseName.get()}"

                val javaComponent = 
                from(components["java"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other than the output I included above, these are the tasks that are done:

```
> Task :baz:compileTestFixturesKotlin
> Task :baz:compileTestFixturesJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :baz:processTestFixturesResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :baz:testFixturesClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :baz:testFixturesJar
> Task :baz:generateMetadataFileForBazPublication
> Task :baz:generatePomFileForBazPublication
> Task :baz:publishBazPublicationToMavenLocal
> Task :baz:publishToMavenLocal
```

EDIT 2:

This is also in `maven-metadata-local.xml`

```
<snapshotVersion>
 <classifier>test-fixtures</classifier>
 <extension>jar</extension>
 <value>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</value>
 <updated>20230213100621</updated>
</snapshotVersion>
```

Comment: Gradle doesn't use the JAR name, it uses the information in the `pom.xml` or [Gradle Module Metadata](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_gradle_module_metadata.html). [This question asks how Gradle differentiates between Kotlin Multiplatform artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73914158/4161471) (which have a different suffix to denotes the target platform, for example `-jvm` or `-js`), which is similar to your question - it might help. I'm not sure why it's not working for you though. Can you update your question to include the console log and `build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. What's weird is that the metadata contains what's under EDIT 2 I would assume is correct

Comment: So it turns out that `testImplementation("foo.bar:baz:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT:test-fixtures")` (note the colon instead of the dash) works. It does seem like a workaround, however. My impression is that the `testFixtures` should be able to figure out this given correct metadata (which seem reasonable to me as it is). @aSemy Do you have any insight here perhaps? Otherwise, I will consider this the answer for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by adding the classifier `test-fixtures` to the implementation statement as such:

`testImplementation("foo.bar:baz:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT:test-fixtures")`

I am still a bit puzzled as to why `testImplementation("foo.bar:baz:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT")` does not work, but this will do.

Answer (score 1):

In a project where test fixtures are going to be used you should use

```
testImplementation(testFixtures("foo.bar:baz:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT"))
```